# constant not inject to config-angularjs

Tags: angularjs, config, inject

I have a problem with angular-config to inject constant "ACCESS_LEVELS"?

Because when I like the code below, gets the message: `Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string`

that is: `Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string`

if I delete the "ACCESS_LEVELS" with inject I do not have access route.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate"])

.constant('ACCESS_LEVELS', {
    guest: 1,
    user: 2,
    admin: 3
});


app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", "ACCESS_LEVELS", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, ACCESS_LEVELS) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template: "",
            label: "Home",
            access_level: ACCESS_LEVELS.user
        })
         .
         .
         .
}]);
```

maybe I made a simple mistake but I can not see it. 
if anyone knows how to solve this problem please help.

regards

Comment: Please provide a fully isolated reproducable live example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including angular-route.js and angular-animate.js file.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/damimuca/1/edit)